# How to make seacrhFunction appear for the last row (from bottom/latest entry) in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on Data entry automation in Google Sheet + Apps Script.
In  my project, there will be multiple entries with same details, only few column will be different.

And I'm having issue with the search function where the data is reflect from top row.
In this project, the latest entry will indicates latest status/task

```
function searchRecord(){
  
  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Tracker"); 

  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("GF");

  var str=shUserForm.getRange("E4").getValue();
  var str=shUserForm.getRange("E6").getValue();
  
  var values=datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  
  var valuesFound=false; 

  //store boolean value
  
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) 
    {

    //storing the value
    var rowValue=values[i]; 
   
    //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
    if (rowValue[6,14]==str){

      shUserForm.getRange("E11").setValue(rowValue[2]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E13").setValue(rowValue[3]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E15").setValue(rowValue[4]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E17").setValue(rowValue[5]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E19").setValue(rowValue[6]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E21").setValue(rowValue[9]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E23").setValue(rowValue[15]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E25").setValue(rowValue[16]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E27").setValue(rowValue[18]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E29").setValue(rowValue[27]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E31").setValue(rowValue[14]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E33").setValue(rowValue[28]);
      shUserForm.getRange("E35").setValue(rowValue[29]);
      valuesFound=true;
      return; //come out from the loop
      
      }
  }

if(valuesFound==false){

  //alert function

  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.alert("Enter correct details");
 }

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: Input will have same details.
Output, if search for the data, only the first row will appear, not the last row.
I have tried for getLastRow variable, but seem there are error.

Situation:
Person A with a unique ID but same details for different task
- At the same time, within a month, new task will be assigned for that same person.
Previous task already completed, but the same person is now will have a new task.

(PS: i'm a newbie in coding)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zEMiO-4dwagPMMGfS-dXWmhgbkTrqmRn4QiYGGiwqlg/edit#gid=1129650873

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're trying to get. So here is a guess. You can try to run the loop backward: `for (var i=values.length; i=0; i--)`